# ¿Por qué desaparecen los iconos de los botones?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar una GUI poco a poco con un curso de youtube, logré que en eclipse al correr mi programa aparecieran 3 botones con sus respectivos iconos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que después intento exportar esa clase como un Runnable Jar File. Cuando me crea el ejecutable y lo abro, los iconos desaparecen misteriosamente.

[image: Esta configuración le doy para exportar]

[image: El archivo creado]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de exportar dicho programa o cómo escribir el programa para que una vez creado el ejecutable, también vayan los iconos con él?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo un proyecto que se llama micia.apps.aplicacion44

Así se llama el paquete, y tengo uno donde tengo las imágenes.

micia.apps.aplicacion44.imagenes  y en esa carpeta tengo gifs, jpgs, etc.

Cuando quiera accesarlas pongo este código:

```
package micia.apps.aplicacion44;

public class Emjemplo1 {


  public JButton dameBoton(String nombreDeImagen, String texto) {
     String nombreAbsoluto = "/micia/apps/aplicacion44/imagenes/"+nombreDeImagen;
     java.net.URL imageURL = this.getClass().getResource(nombreAbsoluto);
     ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageURL, texto);
     JButton button = new JButton();
     button.setIcon(icon);
     return button;
 }

 public JButton dameBotonParaBorrar() {
    return dameBoton("borrar.gif", "borrar");
 }
```